# div and its content toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the html file like this:

```
<div id = "aseaza-menu">

<div class ="menu" >Audio,Video </div><br>
<div class ="menu" >Electrocasnice</div><br>
<div class ="menu" >Ingrijire personala</div><br>
<div class ="menu" >PC</div><br>
<div class ="menu" >Tablete,Telefoane</div><br>

</div>
<div id="box">
<table id = "produse">
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

a div containing more div
and the JavaScript file like this:

```
$(function(){


$("#aseaza-menu").on('mouseover', function(){

$("#box").slideToggle(600);

});
 $("#aseaza-menu").on('mouseout', function(){
    $("#box").hide();
});
});
```

I want once the mouse hover the "aseaza-menu" div, I want it to slide toggle and stop no matter on witch of it's elements my mouse hovers over. But instead it does this: mouse hovers "aseaza-menu" div, "box" div slide Toggles but if I move the mouse over one of its elements like "Audio,Video" the process starts over again(the "box" div hides and slides again). Is there any method apply the slideToggle method on the div and it's content? Sorry for my english,Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use `$("#box").slideDown(600);` ?

Comment: Also use `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Slidetoggle when hovering over parent and children
$('#aseaza-menu').on('mouseover', function(){
  $('#box').slideToggle(600);
});

// When no longer hovering parent div, hide box again
$('#aseaza-menu').on('mouseout', function(){
    $('#box').hide();

// But don't hide box when no longer hovering children
}).children().on('mouseout', function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

if you don't want to hide the box when no longer hover children, replace the bottom 3 lines of code with

```
});
```

Your question is not very clearly formulated but this is my code based on what I could understand from it.

Comment: not really, I want to ignore when hovering the children,like I hover over the parent, "box" div slides and shows no matter what, even when I hover over the children, but I want it to hide when I exit the parent div